# How do you know what will make the boolean modifier work?

Tags: modifiers, geometry

The green mesh and the blue mesh are identical except the green one started out as a 3mm diameter cylinder and the blue one started out as a 6.5mm diameter cylinder.

I hate to say it this way because I've been making a lot of changes as I go along so it's not 100% true but basically use of the boolean modifier has been pretty much hit and miss. Every time I use it I have no idea if it will work or not.

Once I get the blue mesh to carve into **any** spot on the red mesh I have to get it to carve over where the green mesh has already carved and I'm certain that will be more difficult.

Here's what I'm having trouble with:
[image]
[image]

and this is the general idea of how the blue and green meshes fit into the red mesh:

[image]

It's from an earlier model before I was as good with blender as I am now, lol. It basically forms one of those interlocking tracks that are used to hold parts together.

Finally, [here](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1gtN-NmvZbsOmyvgFWDkoBzNQUfCOgBx_/view?usp=sharing) is a stripped down version of the file that contains only the three meshes in question. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Well, for what it's worth I got it. I just recreated the blue mesh and tried again (https://i.imgur.com/x4i07Sq.png). If I had to guess I'd say maybe I added a solidify to the blue mesh and forgot about it and that messed things up somehow. I really don't know why the blue mesh doesn't work but recreating it worked.